# Hibernate: @OneToMany with @EmbeddedId

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to associate 2 pojos using `@OneToMany` unidirectional association.
Here are my Pojos:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="game_template")
class SingleGameTemplate {
   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long m_id;

   @OneToMany
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
   @JoinColumns({ //
      @JoinColumn(name = "game_template_id"), //
      @JoinColumn(name = "type")//
   })
   @MapKey(name = "m_id.m_type")
   private Map<ScoreFeatureType, ScoreFeature> m_features;

   ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "score_feature")
class Feature {
  @EmbeddedId
  private FeatureId m_id;

  ...
}

@Embeddable
class FeatureId {
   @Column(name = "game_template_id")
   private m_templateId

   @Column(name = "type")
   private FeatureType m_type;

   ...
}
```

The exception I'm getting:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.shareddata.entity.game.SingleGameTemplate from com.shareddata.entity.game.ScoreFeature has the wrong number of column. should be 1
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:657)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindOneToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:939)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:854)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.MapBinder$1.secondPass(MapBinder.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1684)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1652)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:473)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:84)number of column. should be 1
```

Notice that my table contains 2 fields as the primary keys, for example:

```
id   template_id
 1        'A'
 1        'B'
 1        'C'
 2        'A'
 2        'B'
 2        'C'
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: When asking about code that throws an exception, post that code, and post the complete and exact stack trace of the exception.

Comment: But `m_id.m_templateId` is not a valid column name. Don't put a dot in your column name.

Comment: right, so how do I tell @JoinColumn to map it according to composite key (`id` and `template_id`) ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumns.html

Comment: I have tried using multiple `@JoinColumn` - and updated the question with the exception

Comment: Wait, I went too fast to read the code. You have a OneToMany between SingleGameTemplate and ScoreFeature. So the join column is a column of the ScoreFeature table, used to reference a row of SingleGameTemplate. SingleGameTemplate has a unique ID column. So why would you need two join columns? That's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: `SingleGameTemplate` has PK `id` and I would like to join it with `ScoreFeature` which PK is `game_template_id` and `type` (@EmbeddedId). `SingleGameTemplate.id = ScoreFeature.game_template_id`.

Comment: The thing that makes it more special than the usual case is that the joined table has a composite Id.

Comment: If the join column is also part of the ID of ScoreFeature, then it should be a bidirectional OneToMany/ManyToOne, and the mapping should be defined on the manyToOne. See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-basic-embeddedid-manytoone-mapping-example

Comment: I'll look into @OneToMany bidirectional, although I don't understand the reason behind it.

Comment: Yep, bidirectional solve this case - Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciate it!